# Using multiple audio files with onclick=playSound command for cross-browser support

Tags: javascript, html, html5-audio

Im currently using the onclick=playsound code on this link (http://webdesign.about.com/od/sound/a/play_sound_oncl.htm) with some styled radio buttons to allow a few single audiofiles to be toggled.

The only problem is that I can't figure out how to get cross browser support with this method.

Is there any way to do this?

```
                                <div class="tabs" id="play-bar">
                                <div class="tab">
                                    <input type="radio" id="tab-1" name="tab-group-1" checked onclick="playSound('soundfile1.wav');">
                                    <label for="tab-1">1</label>
                                </div>
                                <div class="tab">
                                    <input type="radio" id="tab-2" name="tab-group-1" onclick="playSound('soundfile2.wav');">
                                    <label for="tab-2">2</label>
                                </div></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

just use jQuery for Cross-browser complainant code.

HTML

```
<div class="tabs" id="play-bar">
  <div class="tab">
    <input type="radio" id="tab-1" name="tab-group-1" checked>
    <label for="tab-1">1</label>
  </div>
  <div class="tab">
    <input type="radio" id="tab-2" name="tab-group-1">
    <label for="tab-2">2</label>
  </div>
</div>
```

jQuery

```
$('input[name="tab-group-1"]').click(function(){
  var num = $(this).prop('id').split('-')[1];
  playSound('soundfile'+ num +'.wav');
});
```